# Easy question about subdifferential of a functional on $L^2(0,T;L^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, bochner-spaces, subgradient

Define $J:L^1(0,T;L^1) \to \mathbb{R}$ by 
$$J(v) = \int_0^T \int_\Omega \Psi(v)$$
where $\Psi(v) = \int_0^v \beta(s)\;ds$ where $\beta$ is a nice function that passes through the origin.

We have that $\partial J(u) = \{v \in L^2(0,T;L^2) \mid v = \beta(u) \text{ a.e}\}.$ Why does this mean that

> for all $w \in L^2(0,T;L^2)$
>   $$\int_0^T \int_{\Omega}(\beta(u)u + \Psi(w)) \geq \int_0^T\int_\Omega(\Psi(u) + \beta(u)w)?$$

I thought this may be due to definition of the subdifferential but it doesn't appear so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that as a part of being "nice", $\beta$   should be increasing. This makes $\Psi$ convex.

Let $v=\beta(u)$ and consider the  functional 
$$E(w) =  \int_{0}^T \int_\Omega (v w - \Psi(w)) = \left(\int_{0}^T \int_\Omega v w \right)- J(w)$$
Its derivative is zero when  $w=u$, because then it is equal to 
$$ h\mapsto \int_{0}^T \int_\Omega (v h - \beta(u) h) = 0$$
Therefore, $u$ is a point of minimum of $E$. This means
$$\int_{0}^T \int_\Omega (v u - \Psi(u))  \le \int_{0}^T \int_\Omega (v w - \Psi(w)) $$
which is the desired inequality.